# Develop an iPhone GPS time based POI app?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, point-of-interest

I'd like to create an app that provides "time based" POI landmark markers on a typical map interface. For example, between the hours of 4:00pm-7:00pm display a bar that advertises their happy hour through the app.

Is the best way to handle this via a private database? Can I seed my records from other APIs that provide POI?  Like Museums, libraries, etc? Perhaps use their POI records with my pivate time-based records?

I am a java PC app developer and have no experience with the iPhone. Where should I look to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Use NodeJS, Express and MongoDB on a server, implement a web site which allows shops to register their location, time, and specials which are stored in the MongoDB.

Implement a JSON Restful service to pull the MongoDB data records for a remote mobile application.

Create a mobile web app using JQuery Mobile which uses the API and Google maps to present the data. Use HTML5 and javascript so that you mobile app works on all smart devices without the need of any market.

My first pass on the idea. But know that this is in the domain of big guys like Google, they will be doing this if they don't already have it covered.